# independent $L^2$ distance random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

When you have independent random variables with $L^2$ distance between 
each of them is some fixed constant. Say expectation of each of those random variables are zero

THEN

How can i conclude that that this sequence can NOT converge in probability 
to a limit?

I believe this should be true.

How to show it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a sequence can converge in probability.  For example, take the sequence $X_1$, $X_2$, $\dots$ of independent random variables where
$$
X_n:=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2^n, & \text{with probability } 2^{-2n}\\
-2^n, & \text{with probability } 2^{-2n}\\
0, & \text{with probability } 1-2^{-(2n-1)}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then, for each $n$, $${\Bbb E}X_n=2^{-2n}\cdot2^n+2^{-2n}\cdot(-2^n)=0,$$
$${\Bbb E}X_n^2=2^{-2n}\cdot (2^n)^2+2^{-2n}\cdot(-2^n)^2=2,$$
so for all $i<j$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\Bbb E}[(X_i-X_j)^2]&=&{\Bbb E}(X_i^2)+{\Bbb E}(X_j^2)-2({\Bbb E}X_i)({\Bbb E}X_j)\\
&=&2+2-2\cdot0\cdot0\\
&=&4.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, this sequence satisfies the given conditions, but it converges in probability to $0$.